# Why not validating?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

im trying to validate my form, 
but for some reason the **SSN** field wont work :(

i have:

```
    validate: function () {
        contact.message = '';
        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-name').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Name is required. ';
        }

        var ssn = $('#contact-container #contact-ssn').val();
        if (!ssn) {
            contact.message += 'SSN is required. ';
        }
        else {
            if (!contact.validateSSN(ssn)) {
                contact.message += 'SSN is invalid. ';
            }
        }

        var email = $('#contact-container #contact-email').val();
        if (!email) {
            contact.message += 'Email is required. ';
        }
        else {
            if (!contact.validateEmail(email)) {
                contact.message += 'Email is invalid. ';
            }
        }

        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-message').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Message is required.';
        }

        if (contact.message.length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
```

and

```
            validateSSN: function (ssn) {
            // 
            if (!/^[0-9]{9}$/)
                return false; 
                    else 
                    { 
                       return true;
                    }

    },
```

The e-mail section i have works fine, but the SSN section just accepts anything along as its not empty. What am i missing? 
thank you

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle.net with the code and the test case that is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!/^[0-9]{9}$/ will always return false since the /.../ part evaluates to a regex object and an object is always evaluated to true.

You probably want to `if (!/^[0-9]{9}$/.test(ssn))`

EDIT: Even simpler:

```
validateSSN: function (ssn) {
  return /^[0-9]{9}$/.test(ssn);
}
```

Comment: That's dangerous, because then it will return `undefined`. See my updated answer. The `test` method will always return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need -

```
 if (!/^[0-9]{9}$/.test(ssn))
```

instead of -

```
 if (!/^[0-9]{9}$/)
```

That should tell you if the `ssn` value matches your RegEx or not. I think `!/^[0-9]{9}$/` will always return false.

Comment: ty you :) but it still does not work after changing that coding

Comment: WOOP, i fixed it.... i had to remove

  `else 
                    { 
                       return true;
                    }`